# Logic and code help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logic, solution

Here are my models and associations:

- User has many Awards
- Award belongs to User
- Prize has many Awards
- Award belongs to Prize

Let's pretend that there are four Prizes (captured as records):

- Pony
- Toy
- Gum
- AwesomeStatus

Every day a User can be awarded one or more of these Prizes.  But the User can only receive each Prize once per day.  If the User wins AwesomeStatus, for ex, a record is added to the Awards table with a fk to User and Prize.  Obviously, if the User doesn't win the AwesomeStatus for the day, no record is added.

At the end of the day (before midnight, let's say), I want to return a list of Users who lost their AwesomeStatus.  (Of course, to lose your AwesomeStatus, you had to have the day before.)  Unfortunately, in my case, I don't think observers will work and will have to rely on a script.  Regardless, how would you go about determining which Users lost their AwesomeStatus?  Note: don't make your solution overly dependent on the period of time -- in this case a day.  I want to maintain flexibility in how many times per whatever period Users have an opportunity to win the prize (and to also lose it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

The class Award should also have a column awarded_at which contains the day the prize was awarded. So when it is time to create the award it can be done like this:

```
# This will make sure that no award will be created if it already exists for the current date
@user.awards.find_or_create_by_prize_id_and_awarded_at(@prize.id, Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

And then we can have a scope to load all users with an award that will expire today and no active awards for the supplied prize.

```
# user.rb
scope :are_losing_award, lambda { |prize_id, expires_after| 
  joins("INNER JOIN awards AS expired_awards ON users.id = expired_awards.user_id AND expired_awards.awarded_at = '#{(Time.now - expires_after.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}'
         LEFT OUTER JOIN awards AS active_awards ON users.id = active_awards.user_id AND active_awards.awarded_at > '(Time.now - expires_after.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}' AND active_awards.prize_id = #{prize_id}").
  where("expired_awards.prize_id = ? AND active_awards.id IS NULL", prize_id)
}
```

So then we can call it like this:

```
# Give me all users who got the prize three days ago and has not gotten it again since
User.are_losing_award(@prize.id, 3)
```

There might be some ways to write the scope better with ARel queries or something, I'm no expert with that yet, but this way should work until then :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd add an integer "time period" field to awards, which stands for a given period of time (day, week, 5 hour period, whatever you want).

Now, you can search the awards table for users who have the award status at t-1, but not at t:

```
SELECT prev.user_id 
FROM awards prev 
OUTER JOIN awards current ON prev.user_id = current.user_id 
AND prev.prize_id = current.prize_id 
AND current.time_period = 1000
WHERE prev.prize_id = 1 
AND current.prize_id IS NULL 
AND prev.time_period = 999
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use updated_at, or add an awarded_at like suggested above and use it like this:

```
scope :awarded, proc {|date| where(["updated_at <= ?", date])}
```

In your Award model. Print it like this, maybe:

```
awesome_status = Prize.find_by_name('AwesomeStatus')
p "Users who do not have AwesomeStatus anymore:"

User.all.each {|user| p user.username if user.awards.awarded(1.day.ago).collect(&:id).include?(awesome_status)}
```

If you want it to be dynamic, displayed somewhere, etc. throw a 'lasts_for' into Prize and compare against it and simply write a maintenance cronjob that sets an 'active' boolean on Award to false instead of deleting the association.